# Instrumental Variables with Missing Observations in the Endogneous Regressor

Tags: missing-data, instrumental-variables

I have 10k observations for a dependent variable $Y$ and an endogenous regressor $X$ with many missing observations (90%). I also have an instrument $Z$ without missings. I know that the values for $X$ are missing at random.

The naive approach to take care of the endogneity would be to run IV on the subsample without missing $X$s. This seems not optimal to me, because it ignores the information on $Y$ and $Z$ in the subsample with missing $X$: 
Since $X$ is missing at random, I can assume that the relationship between $X$ and $Z$ is the same among those observations.
So,
optimally I would run the first stage with the subsample with non-missing $X$s and the the second stage on the full sample, which should give me more power.

Hence my questions:

- Are there issues I neglected here?
- Are there papers about this?
- If I estimate the first and second stage on two different subsamples, how to I get standard errors for my IV estimates?

Comment: Note that I am cross-posting a similar question here: https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1492342-instrumental-variables-with-many-missing-values-in-the-endogenous-regressor

Answer (score 2):

Your approach seems reasonable as long as you are confident about the missing completely at random assumption. I couldn't find any specific papers about this (I found some papers about missing instruments, but not missing endogenous variables), but here's how I would proceed for deriving an asymptotically valid distribution for your proposed estimator. I'm going to assume $X, Z$ are both scalars, but if this is wrong, you should be able to generalize the logic here in a fairly straightforward way. Instead of thinking about IV as a two step estimator, it may be more useful here to think about it as a method of moments estimator:
$$\hat\beta^{IV} = \frac{\widehat{Cov}(Z,Y)}{\widehat{Cov}(Z,X)}$$
Where the numerator can be computed with respect to the full data, but the denominator must be estimated with a restricted dataset. My gut tells me that this estimator might be equivalent to the one you were proposing, but I haven't been able to find an easy proof of this fact.

The asymptotic model I have in mind is that you have $n\to\infty$ and data is sampled i.i.d. with $X$ censored randomly and independently with probability $p$. Let $A_{nm}, A_m$ be respectively the sample corresponding to the non-missing and missing data where $A = X,Y,Z$. Additionally, let $p_{nm}, p_m$ be the proportion of the data that is missing or not (so $p_{nm} = 1 - p_m$). Then by the law of total covariance, we have
$$\hat\beta^{IV} = \frac{\widehat{Cov}(Z_{nm},Y_{nm}) p_{nm} + \widehat{Cov}(Z_{m},Y_{m}) p_{m} + \widehat{Cov}_{s \in nm, m}(E[X | s], E[Y | s])}{\widehat{Cov}(Z_{nm},X_{nm})}$$
The 3rd term in the numerator is $o_p(1)$ under your assumption that $X$ is missing completely at random. But then by continuous mapping, you can write that
$$\hat\beta^{IV} = \hat\beta^{IV}_{nm} p_{nm} + \frac{\widehat{Cov}(Z_{m},Y_{n})}{\widehat{Cov}(Z_{nm},X_{nm})} p_m + o_p(1)$$
where $\hat\beta^{IV}_{nm}$ is just the IV estimator on the non-missing data. From here, it should be possible to use Slutsky's theorem and delta method on the vector of random variables $\left(\hat\beta^{IV}_{nm}, \widehat{Cov}(Z_{m},Y_{n}),\widehat{Cov}(Z_{nm},X_{nm}), p_m\right)$ fairly easily since each of these has an easy to compute variance, and the only pair that does not have zero covariance is $\hat\beta_{nm}^{IV}$ and $\widehat{Cov}(Z_{nm},X_{nm})$.

Edit: If you don't want to do the above, you could always try to bootstrap to get standard errors.

Edit 2: A potentially more general approach to what I did above is to think of what you’re doing as a 2 step estimator and work from there by modifying the results in section 6 of Newey and McFadden’s 1994 handbook of econometrics [chapter](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1573441205800054) on large sample theory to account for a smaller sample size in the first step.